# Implementing JQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement JQuery Datepicker. I added to my JSF code the JavaScript. This is the HTML output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
            <title>DX-57 History Center</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resources/css/themes/nvidia.com/images/favicon.ico" />
            <link href="resources/css/helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="resources/css/dropdown.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="resources/css/default.advanced.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
            <link href="resources/css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/tabs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){                                
                // Datepicker
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    inline: true,
                    showWeek: true,
                    firstDay: 1
                });
            });            
        </script><script type="text/javascript" src="/test/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script></head><body>
        <!-- demo inset for with validator -->
        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal" style="margin: 0 auto">
                <li><a href="/SR_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserNav.jsf" class="dir">Home</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Dashboard.jsf">Dashboard</a></li>
                    </ul>       
                </li>
                <li><a href="Sessions.jsf" class="dir">Sessions</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Application.jsf" class="dir">Application</a>
                    <ul>                
                        <li><a href="Glassfish.jsf">Glassfish</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Linux.jsf" class="dir">Linux</a>                   
                </li>
                <li><a href="Database.jsf" class="dir">Database</a> 
                    <ul>                
                        <li><a href="History.jsf">History</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                   
            </ul>          

        </div>  

        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"><img src="resources/images/logo_databasez.png" alt="Demo Insert Form" style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">
<form id="j_idt13" name="j_idt13" method="post" action="/test/Database.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt13" value="j_idt13" />

                        <div id="settingsdiv" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px"><table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Session ID</td>
<td><input id="j_idt13:sessionid" type="text" name="j_idt13:sessionid" onblur="mojarra.ab(this,event,'blur',0,'j_idt13:sessionidMessage')" /><span id="j_idt13:sessionidMessage"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td><input id="j_idt13:datepicker" type="text" name="j_idt13:datepicker" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Login Time</td>
<td><input id="j_idt13:logintime" type="text" name="j_idt13:logintime" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Refresh Time</td>
<td><input id="j_idt13:lastrefreshtime" type="text" name="j_idt13:lastrefreshtime" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User IP</td>
<td><input id="j_idt13:userip" type="text" name="j_idt13:userip" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


                        </div>   

                        <div id="settingstwodiv" style="width:150px; height:60px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:380px; left:800px"><input type="submit" name="j_idt13:j_idt32" value="Create User" />

                        </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="7591771537138283258:6254434046150824528" autocomplete="off" />
</form> 

                </div>   

            </div>  
        </div></body>
</html>
```

But when I click on the input filed nothing happens. Is there something missing? Into the example that I found the calendar was using `<div id="datepicker"></div>` to be displayed. I use input field in my example.

Best Wishes

**EDIT**

I added `div` to visualize only the calendar.

I added the `div` here:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:panelGroup>Session ID</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="sessionid" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['sessionid']}" 
                                                 validator="#{ValidatorController.validatebean}">                                        
                                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="sessionidMessage" />                                          
                                    </h:inputText>
                                    <h:message id="sessionidMessage" for="sessionid" />
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <h:panelGroup>Date</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                     <div id="datepicker"></div>
                                    <h:inputText id="datepicker" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['userid']}" >                                       
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <h:panelGroup>Login Time</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="logintime" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['logintime']}" >
                                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="35"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <h:panelGroup>Last Refresh Time</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="lastrefreshtime" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['lastrefreshtime']}" >
                                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="35"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <h:panelGroup>User IP</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="userip" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['userip']}" >
                                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="15"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                            </h:panelGrid>
```

[image]

I would like to open the calendar like this example [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) - when I click on the input field.

It seems that there is other way to call the calendar in JSF.

EDIT 2

Is this JavaScript correct?

```
function calendar(){                                
    // Datepicker
    datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1
    });
}
```

I will call it with this code:

```
<h:inputText onclick="calendar" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['userid']}" >
```

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: Firebug in not showing any errors.

Comment: I failed to find a div/input with `id="datepicker"` in your code. Did you mean `$("#j_idt13:datepicker").datepicker(...)`?

Comment: datepicker where is this input elemebt >

Comment: $('#j_idt13:datepicker').datepicker({});  try this.

Comment: This is the JSF page. I updated the post.

Comment: Maybe the solution will be to edit the JavaScript code as function and call it into the JSF input field? What is the proper way to edit the JavaScript code as function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is JSF specific. You have to use `styleClass="datepicker"` in order to call the `#datepicker` JS.

Answer (score 3):

datepicker id is missed here. you are calling wrong id . try like this and you used `:` in your attribute, by using slash

```
$(function(){
    $('#j_idt13\\:datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){                                
                // Datepicker
                $('#j_idt13:logintime').datepicker({
                    inline: true,
                    showWeek: true,
                    firstDay: 1
                });
            });            
        </script>
```

Change it to this. Your selector was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make "#datepicker" the ID of the input box.

e.g.

```
        $(function(){                                
            // Datepicker
            $('#j_idt13:datepicker').datepicker({
                inline: true,
                showWeek: true,
                firstDay: 1
            });
        });
```

I'd recomend researching [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 2):

HIya **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/8Hp26/

your id is different it looks like you are using some kind of template or user controller to generate the html, in the demo I have added a new class = foo or you can try and escape the `:` in you JQuery.

**Note** to use escape add `\\:` but adding class should do the trick like shown in demo.

hope this helps.

**code**

```
 $(function(){                                
            // Datepicker
          //  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
         $('.foo').datepicker({                
                inline: true,
                showWeek: true,
                firstDay: 1
            });
        });​
```

Answer (score 1):

The id of your input field is not `datepicker` but `j_idt13:datepicker`.
You have to use this id when calling the datepicker component:

```
$(function(){
    $('#j_idt13\\:datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1
    });
});
```

The `\\` is for escaping the `:` as it is otherwise used by jQuery.

However I would recommend an using an id **without** `:` in it.

Comment: I thought about that but this won't work I tried in jsfiddle i reckon you need to escape `:` just an idea